# How to use CASE statement in SQL to change an empty field in one column based on another column

Tags: sql, if-statement, case

I'm just starting with SQL with no training but the job suddenly requires it. So thank you in advance for any help.

Let's say I have a query that returns 3 columns. Some of the cells in column 3 are empty and I would like to fill them in with values based on column1.

example:

```
CASE column1 = 'Individual' then Column3 should show 'Individual' not empty, but if column1 = 'group' them column3 needs to show "group" else no change.  

SELECT column1, column2, column3,  
CASE  
    WHEN column1 = 'Individual' THEN Column3 = 'Individual'  
    WHEN column1 = "Group' THEN comlumn3 = 'Group'  
END  
FROM tablename
```

Comment: You are nearly there, change it like this `WHEN column1 = 'Individual' THEN 'Individual' ... END as column3` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to `select` data and not change the table values you can use case as you tried:

```
SELECT column1, column2,
CASE  
    WHEN column3 IS NULL THEN Column1  
    ELSE column3
END as column3
FROM tablename
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I believe your method creates column3. I already have clolumn3 in the table but some of the data in column3 are blank. So I want to fill those blank ones with text values based on column1. Column3 doesn't always have to match col1. Column1 has 3 options, if "Individual" I want col3 to change from blank to "Individual" if "Group" I want it to change blank in col3 to "group" or anything else I want. ELSE col3 should remain unchanged and return the data it already has.

Comment: What my query does is the changing the aspect of `Column3` based on its own values. In case it is NULL then it will apply value from `Column1` (in case `Col1` is `Individual` it will return `Individual`, in case of `Group` it will return `Group`). Otherwise it will return `Col3`. If this doesnt work as described it's because `Col1` is not NULL in that case but maybe just empty String. This can be checked with `Column3 = ''`

Comment: I didn't see your solution as an answer at first, but after getting to know SQL a bit more I realized this was the solution. Thank you